# Custom UITableViewCell from XIB: contentView width is always the same

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I've created a custom `UITableViewCell` with an `xib` file. In there I have placed several labels and views relative to the width of the `contentView`. Unfortunately the `contentView.bounds.width` property stays always the same no matter which device is selected.

My ViewController is also loaded from nib:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    init(title: String) {
        super.init(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
    }     

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        return cell
    }

}
```

In the `CustomTableViewCell` class I print out the width property of the content view:

```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        print("self.contentView.bounds.width: \(self.contentView.bounds.width)") 
   }
```

This always prints out the width set in the Interface Builder, even though it should follow the width of the `tableView` which uses AutoLayout:

[image]

Trying to set the cell's frame before returning didn't work:

```
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 71)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `autolayout` then count your `width` in `cellforrowAtindexpath` and you will get proper width. `awakeFromNib` gets called before your cell get autolayout so it is giving same width as set in `interface builder`.

Second thing if you are using autolayout then setting `frame` has no meaning. if you want to change `height or width` then you should take `outlet of your constraint (height or width)` and you can change it's `constant` to desired value!

If you want to change height only then you can play with `heightForRowAtIndexPath` with `if else` which return desire height as per condition!

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about those. But what do you mean by counting the width in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Why doesn't the `UITableViewCell` automatically have the width of the `tableView`?

Comment: `UITableViewCell` get width as per your constraint but after `awakeFromNib` get called. so in `awakeFromNib` you will not get right frame!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+**

You can use following code, it will set the frame of XIB cell and you can adjust content also with help of XIB height and width.

```
let cellRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: postTableView.frame.size.width, height: imageHeight)
cell?.frame = cellRect
```

**Hope it will work**